How to connect to a Neo4j desktop database from WSL2
I've set up a local Neo4j database on my Windows laptop, running on the default Bolt port bolt://localhost:7687. I'm currently working within the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and trying to access the Neo4j instance from a Python script in WSL. However, I'm encountering a connection error.
From what I've read, it seems that WSL might have issues accessing services running on localhost in Windows (referencing this documentation and this Stack Overflow thread). Could this be the root of the problem? If so, what's the best way to resolve this and allow WSL to connect to the Neo4j instance on my Windows host?
Initially, I tried connecting to the database directly from WSL without success. I then attempted to follow the documentation, but I’m unclear on how to implement the following recommendation:

You will need to edit the settings/config for your database to have it bind to 0.0.0.0 (all local IPs) or the specific local IP you want to connect on.

Any guidance on how to properly configure this would be greatly appreciated.
